# how to make login page in iphone using sqlite

Tags: iphone, sqlite, ios6

I am trying to create to create login page in iPhone using sqlite.
I need suggestions ,how to create login form with username /password authentication. For successful login - user should navigate to next page like UITableview.Otherwise giving user a error message: login failed. Please help me. I am new to the Programming.

Comment: I'd encourage you to (a) google "iOS sqlite tutorial" as this is a non-trivial topic, not conducive to simple answer; (b) if you write your own sqlite code, consider using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), which takes a lot of the hassles out of sqlite programming; (c) you might consider using Core Data instead.

Answer (score 1):

First you create registration page and after this code apply in your login view..

```
if([uername.text isEqualToString:@""] || [password.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Here comes a block." message:@"You missed something, please check your details and try again." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
    }
else
    {
    //insert data

    NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"select * from registration_table where username=\"%@\" and password=\"%@\"",uername.text,password.text];
      NSLog(@"%@",query);

      //select * from registration_tbl where username="d" and password="d"

        array=[app.sk lookupAllForSQL:query];
        NSLog(@"%@",[array description]);
        if (array.count>0) 
            {
            app.currrentid=[[array objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"uid"];
                NSLog(@"%@",app.currrentid);
                UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"" message:@"login successful" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
                                    messageviewcontroller *log = [[messageviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"messageviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
                [self.navigationController pushViewController:log animated:YES];
                [log release];
                log.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
                [self presentModalViewController:log animated:YES];

                }
        else 
            {
                UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Here comes a block." message:@"angry" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alert show];
                [alert release];

                }


        uername.text=@"";
        password.text=@"";

        //push the view
        }
```

i hope this code useful for you.

Comment: BTW, the technique of building the SQL with `stringWithFormat` is a very bad idea. You should be using `?` placeholders in your SQL, and then using `sqlite3_bind_text` for those two parameters. You're opening yourself up to SQL errors (e.g. what if the user's password had a quotation mark in it) or SQL injection attacks. I'm also not a fan of storing the password in clear text rather than encrypting it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a table for storing username and password
2. Input the value such that password is encrypted.
3. Make a login page with Textfield for username and password
4. On button action collect the username and password from textfield

.

```
-(IBAction)loginbuttonPressed:(id)sender
    {
        if (check username is in table == success)
        {
            //encrypt the password entered compare and check for password is true for the username in table
            if(check password is in table= password found success)
            {
                       // Successfully logged in
            }
            else
            {
                //alert "Password Incorrect"
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // Alert "Username not found"
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First thing** you need to do is add `libsqlite3.dylib` to your list of frameworks.

As a **Second thing** you should start reading the [SQLite3 documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/docs.html), especially the [five-minute guide](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html). If you want some reference to understand how to **"Save Data to the SQLite Database"** and **"Extract Data from the SQLite Database"** , you can always check the Beautiful Tutorial : [An Example SQLite based iPhone Application](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_SQLite_based_iPhone_Application)

**Third and Most Importing** thing you need to do is : **Read Above Links** ( Reference to Line in your Question *`I AM new to the Programming`* ).

At last, I cans say you : Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 0):

First of create 1 sample database with User Table with UserName & Password fields.

Then, copy database into application while installing first time.

```
- (void) copyDatabaseIfNeeded 
{
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
   NSError *error;
   dbPath = [self getDBPath];
   BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

   if(!success) 
   {
       NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbSample.sqlite3"];
       success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:dbPath error:&error];
       if (!success)
           NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
   }
}

/********* Database Path *********/ 
- (NSString *) getDBPath 
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask,YES);
    NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    return [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"dbSample.sqlite3"];
}
```

Then, check on Validate Button Click,

```
-(IBAction)validateUser:(id)sender
{
    if (sqlite3_open([[appDel getDBPath] UTF8String], &dbTest) == SQLITE_OK) 
    {
        NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT UserName, Password FROM tblUser Where UserName = \"%@\"",[txtUserName text]];
        NSLog(@"%@",querySQL);
        const char *sql = [querySQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_stmt *searchStatement;
        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dbTest, sql, -1, &searchStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {
            if (sqlite3_step(searchStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) 
            {
               infoUserName = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 0)];
               infoUserPassword = [[NSString alloc] initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(searchStatement, 1)];
               NSLog(@"User : %@, Password : %@",infoUserName, infoPassword);
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(searchStatement);
    }
    sqlite3_close(dbTest);
}
```

May be, it'll help you.

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't use `stringWithFormat` to build sql (what if username had quotation mark in it, either innocently or in a SQL injection attack). Use `?` placeholders and `sqlite3_bind_text`. Not good idea to store userid/password in clear text. Probably should be logging `sqlite3_errmsg` on failures, notably `sqlite_prepare_v2`. You might want to ensure `sqlite3_column_text` didn't return `NULL` (it shouldn't, but you should make sure) before passing it to `initWithUTF8String`, or else you'll get exception. Also, `sqlite3_close` should probably go inside the "if `sqlite3_open` successful" block.